# Conditions in profile and membership

Tags: wordpress, civimember

I have individual members that can have different criteria for example:
Are you an English teacher : checkbox yes / no
(if yes :: appears in contribution form): what is your degree?: check boxes: bachelor/master/PhD
(if no :: appears in contribution form): what is your level at TOEFL? : free text.

How do I set conditions in forms using WordPress? Our membership for individual (member) is very complex and I don't want the form to be 1000 lines long.

I couldn't find this in the documentation.
Any help?
regards
Guillaume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention which CMS you are using but if Drupal, you might find it easier to do this with a webform.

If you're not on Drupal and want to do this with profiles then take a look at the [Profile Conditionals extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/profile-conditionals)

Comment: We are using WordPress. Thanks for your answer i will have a look at this extension.

Comment: I looked at this extension. Is there an other way to do this in graphical mode within WordPress?

Comment: Possibly with https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm  Search on here for Caldera forms.

Comment: Thank ou for your answer Aidan. I will have a look at this extension.

Comment: I switched to Drupal and Webform is THE tool for forms with conditions. I recommend to switch to Drupal for CiviCRM